# How to change loopback network mask or redirect subnet to another interface

Tags: networking, ip, route, ip-routing, loopback

I have the following problem.
First of all. Here are my interfaces.

```
# ip addr
ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.1.15/24 brd 10.10.1.255 scope global eth1
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe28:b0c4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you can see the loopback interface serves following network `127.0.0.1/8`, the network mask is `255.0.0.0`.

My problem is that I need to route all traffic for example for the network `127.22.0.0/16` to the interface `eth1`.

I have following routes now

```
default via 10.10.1.2 dev eth1
default via 10.10.1.2 dev eth1  metric 203
10.10.1.0/24 dev eth1  scope link
10.10.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.1.15  metric 203
10.10.1.2 dev eth1  scope link
```

And I try to add the following route

```
ip route add 127.22.0.0/16 via 10.10.1.2 dev eth1
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Here is the output

```
root@sys:/ # ip route flush cache
ip route flush cache
root@sys:/ # ip route get "127.22.0.1"
ip route get "127.22.0.1"
local 127.22.0.1 dev lo  src 127.0.0.1
    cache <local>
```

As you can see all packets are still redirected to loopback.

What is the best solution for that problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [What is the rest of the 127.0.0.0/8 address space used for?](https://serverfault.com/questions/402938/what-is-the-rest-of-the-127-0-0-0-8-address-space-used-for) , the `127.0.0.0/8` block is the loopback block, and all packets destined to the block must be looped back to the origin host.

So, you cannot route those packets anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there is no really way to fix this somehow ? Kernel module, iptables, somehow, I really need it.

Comment: I think you actual problem is something different and you are hunting a XY problem. Why do you need to route *127.22.0.0/16*? Any service or machine you want to reach?

Comment: @Thomas , the problem that there is no way to change 127.22.0.0, third party software forces to use it, and on windows it works fine.

Comment: You might be able to change kernel behavior by building your own custom version of the kernel that changes how the `lo` interface works. However, you really need to know what you are doing to make this happen. Your 3rd party software is something very weird when it is doing things like that.