# Connection refused while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, django, fastcgi

I'm running a Django website with nginx via fastcgi running on a TCP port 9000 on localhost. Everything appears to work correctly, but the error log is filled with lines like these:

> 2012/11/19 14:05:07 [error] 21849#0: *2990 connect() failed (111:
>   Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
>   71.249.131.121, server: localhost, request: "GET /charity/ajax/preload_project/ HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://127.0.1.1:9000", host: "www.dailygiver.org", referrer:
>   "http://www.dailygiver.org/charity/browse/"

The strange part is it still seems to serve the request just fine. Netstat confirms that the fastcgi process is running and listening as expected:

> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31455/python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is not the same as `127.0.1.1`.

Comment: Oh duh. I looked at it a bunch of times and never noticed that it's 1.1, not 0.1.  Apparently the hosts file has an entry for 127.0.1.1 as a workaround for a bug: http://serverfault.com/questions/363095/what-does-127-0-1-1-represent-in-etc-hosts.  Removing that entry from hosts resolved the issue.